# How to call and filter only one stock to this df that has a very long index name?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, quantopian

I cannot call a specific stock due to its very long index name.
I used to... for calling under a TICKER column but now its on the index.
`df2 = df[df['TICKER'] == What_Stock1]`

quantopian, self-serve data
[image]

Comment: is [`pandas.Index.get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) what you are looking for?

Comment: How can I call a specific stock with this kind of index?